# Mutual excluding and process synchronization; C++

Tags: c++, process, synchronization, semaphore

I have a problem with 2 processes synchronization. I have 3 X processes and 5 Y processes. Also I have 2 resources - A and B.

Resource'A' may be used by max 3 proceses at the same time, and by accessing to resource 'B' mutual excluding is necessary.

process X and Y:

```
void processX()
{
    while (1)
    {
        AccessToResource(B);

        AccessToResource(A);
    }
}

void processY()
{
    while (1)
    {
        AccessToResource(A);

        AccessToResource(B);
    }
}
```

How can I do that using Semaphores, Mutexes, Events, the shortest way?

For now I have

```
CSemaphore sem(1,5,L"semaph");
```

and using it by sem.Lock() and sem.Unlock() before and after accessing to resource but it's not quite good.

Comment: So you don't need to lock access to both A and B at the same time? The access to each resource can be handled separately from the other?

Comment: Processes X and Y are running at the same time. I don't know how to handle it, it's my first task with something like that

Comment: @Pawel the C++ standard has no notion of a process, and the standard library has no inter process communication API. You'll need to specify the API that you intend to use in the question.

Comment: @user2079303 The terms "process", "semaphore" and "mutex" are commonly known and well-defined concepts. It should be possible to answer using the general concepts without needing specific implementations or APIs. If the OP needs help with implementing the general techniques then the OP can post another question asking about that (with an example of what the OP have tried, of course, and a description of the specific problems with that example, and a link to this question).

Comment: @Pawel Can you please be more specific and elaborate on the problem you have? You say you have tried something "but it's not quite good"? What do you mean by that? Do you want a general answer without using a specific implementation or API? Do you have problem with a specific implementation or API?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude fair enough. However, if Pawel does not need help with implementation, then why tag a language at all?

Comment: @user2079303 That's true, and also why I asked the OP for clarifications.

Comment: It's a task that was given to me by university tutor. The main task is "add code to both of that processes to assure resource 'A' won't be accesed by more than 3 processes, and resource 'B' won't be accesed by 2 processes at the same time". For now i Think that sem.Lock() before accessing to resource 'B' and then sem.Unlock() should be enough, but I don't know how to handle access to resource 'A'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Resource'A' may be used by max 3 proceses

**Counting semaphore** would be suitable here (see [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming))). It works as folows:

You have some counter (thus the name) initialized with 0. Every time some process owns resource A it increases that semaphore by 1. If count hits 3 in your case that'll mean there are already 3 processes using resource 'A'. After process finished using resource 'A' it decreases that counter (semafore) by 1, thus allowing other processes to use that resource.

> by accessing to resource 'B' mutual excluding is necessary

Here a suitable solution would be a [**mutex**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion) (or **binary semaphore**). They both work almost the same - the difference that `mutex` has an emphasis on *owing the resource*.

Comment: `std::mutex` won't help if the OP is actually using *processes* and not threads. It's an implementation detail though, and we don't really know enough to tell if the OP want an implementation-specific answer or a generic answer (which you provided).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, sorry, I just was misleaded by c++ tag. Fixed the answer.

Comment: @Yuriy Ivaskevych Generic answer is okay so as specific implementation. I think that answer is enough for me :) Thank you very much